# How to use a polymorphic function inside a polymorphic function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've implemented (in fact copy and paste) a polymorphic function (skip_col).
I would like to have fast the same function but this time I want it to print something (skip_col2).
I know that I can add another argument to this function to solve the problem. My question is not about to solve this particular case but I'm searching for a general way to use a polymorphic function inside a polymorphic function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_skip_col
AS
    FUNCTION skip_col (tab TABLE, col COLUMNS)
        RETURN TABLE
        PIPELINED ROW POLYMORPHIC USING pkg_skip_col;
        
    FUNCTION skip_col2 (tab TABLE, col COLUMNS)
        RETURN TABLE
        PIPELINED ROW POLYMORPHIC;

    FUNCTION describe (tab IN OUT DBMS_TF.TABLE_T, col DBMS_TF.COLUMNS_T)
        RETURN DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T;

END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_skip_col
AS

    FUNCTION skip_col2 (tab TABLE, col COLUMNS)
        RETURN TABLE
        PIPELINED ROW POLYMORPHIC
     is
     begin
         dbms_output.put_line('write something');
         return skip_col(skip_col2,col);
     end;    
        
    FUNCTION describe (tab IN OUT DBMS_TF.TABLE_T, col DBMS_TF.COLUMNS_T)
        RETURN DBMS_TF.DESCRIBE_T
    AS
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1 .. tab.column.COUNT ()
        LOOP
            FOR j IN 1 .. col.COUNT ()
            LOOP
                tab.column (i).PASS_THROUGH :=
                    tab.column (i).DESCRIPTION.NAME != col (j);
                EXIT WHEN NOT tab.column (i).PASS_THROUGH;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;

        RETURN NULL;
    END;

END;
```

As you can see I haven't added the keyword using for skip_col2. Because I don't want this function to be implemented by default.

I can compile the spec.
But I can't compile the body.

> PLS-00305: previous use of 'SKIP_COL2' conflicts with this use

I don't think that I have the right to implement a polymorphic function myself (with or without the using keyword). Is that true?
Is there another way to resuse a polymorphic function inside a polymorphic function?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=253d3289831d49944cbe368222405aee)

Comment: You are missing a `;` in the specification after the second function and then you are missing another `;` in the declaration after the `RETURN`.

Comment: @MTO Thanks. But it still doesn't work

Comment: It solves the problem asked in the question about the error `Expecting: USING`.

Comment: @MTO what version of Oracle do you use? I can  compile the spec with your modification and Oracle 21(in dbfiddle) but not the body. But with Oracle 19, I still have the same problem.

Comment: In [Oracle 18](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/PIPELINED-clause.html#GUID-FA182210-C68D-4E03-85B9-A6C681099705) the `USING` clause is required by the syntax for a `POLYMORPHIC` table function; however, in [Oracle 19](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/PIPELINED-clause.html#GUID-FA182210-C68D-4E03-85B9-A6C681099705) the syntax changed to make it optional. Are you sure you are on Oracle 19 and not Oracle 18?

Comment: @MTO Yes. I have added 2 screenshoots. the error and the oracle version. I'm using the version 19.00. Perhaps using optional only in version 19.x (like Macro)

Comment: That is syntax highlighting in SQL Developer and is not something the database generates. If you actually try to compile the package and use `SHOW ERRORS;` or `SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;` then you can see the database errors.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? The polymorphic function itself has no body - the package is the implementation. So you can't create a function `skip_col2` that returns something.

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-A496E727-7A54-4F6E-9E8E-82DF7558063E) says: *Polymorphic table functions do not have a function definition (a FUNCTION BODY), the definition is encapsulated in the associated implementation package*. Also please note that this call is invalid, because it uses function name with no arguments: `return skip_col(skip_col2,col);`

Comment: @MTO you're right. I can compile the spec (TOAD error message is a bug). But I can't compile the body. (previous use of 'SKIp_col2) conflichts with this use.

Comment: @ChrisSaxon I have to function f1,f2 that have the same signature. I do not implement f1 directly and  I would like to f2 be like {print something, return f1}

Comment: What do you mean by `print something`? Why do you need this?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon print something. It's not important. It could be dbms_output.put_line('hello_word').

Comment: @ChrisSaxon I do not now need that especially but perhaps later.